# SQL grant execute on multiple objects

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sql-grant

Hi all I want to add execute permissions to a user for multiple objects. But I can't seem to add wildcards into my code.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.CREATESERVERSESSIONS TO [domain\user];
```

this works but I have a lot of stored procedures that start with XU_ now I want grant execute on all stored procedures that start with XU_

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.XU_* TO [domain\user];
```

but that is not working. I hope someone knows a solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use wildcards - you have to grant either to **all** objects (or all objects in a schema) - or then you have to list all objects one by one

Comment: oh that is going to suck... but okay thanks for the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use wildcards - you have to grant either to **all** objects (or all objects in a schema) - or then you have to list all objects one by one.

What you might do is something like this - have SQL Server generate those statements for you:

```
SELECT
   p.Name,
   GrantCmd = 'GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::' + p.name + ' TO [domain\user]'
FROM sys.procedures p
WHERE p.Name LIKE 'XU%'
```

This query will list all procedures that start with `XU` and create a column that contains the `GRANT EXECUTE ON ....` statement for that procedure.

Run this in SQL Server Management Studio, and then just copy the resulting `GrantCmd` column, paste it to a new window, and execute it there.

And if you **really** want to automate this, you could also turn this query into a cursor and then use dynamic SQL to automatically execute those resulting `GrantCmd` statements....

Comment: Simple but brilliant.